# view drupal nodes which are referenced in another node

Tags: php, drupal, module

I have a node which references other nodes.

If I give a user custom access to this node, how do I set it up so that he automatically gets access to those other nodes as well?

Comment: It would probably depend on what you're using the control access on the first node. Have you already chosen a module to handle that part? And are the referencing nodes and the referenced nodes of the same node type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to build your own access-module, [this piece of API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--node_access_example--node_access_example.module/6) is probably the only place that has somewhat decent documentation on what to look at/for.

Your own custom work will come in on `http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--node_access_example--node_access_example.module/6` and the `_update` equivalent. On these hooks/callbacks, you must not only insert the current GRANT, but GRANTS for all the referenced nodes too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_nodereference

Maybe even http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_autoreference is useful (though I'm a bit confused about the module from its decription)